# Share session between two .NET Core app and .NET Framework app different application pool same domain using azure ad - IDX20804 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-authentication

I have a .NET Core application and another .NET Framework application running under the same site (domain) on IIS. Both are working perfectly. But when I add authentication with azure ad on the .NET Core app, I am having some errors (shown below).

.NET Framework app specs:

- Already using authentication with SAML 2.0
- Nothing has been changed in this application
- Has its own web.config file
- Has its own application pool
- Login working fine

.NET Core app specs:

- Using .net core 3.1
- Using Azure AD to authenticate the user
- TenantId and ClientId are setted correctly in appsettings.json file
- Has its own web.config file
- Has its own application pool
- Login working fine locally (with visual studio using iis express) authentication with azure Ad

[IIS site structure - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfpGt.png)

[Application pools - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5aqu.png)

Steps :

1. Login sucessfully with saml
2. Get in the .NET Framework app sucessfully
3. Click on the .net core app
4. Loads for a while and get 3 errors :

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/blablabla/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/blablabla/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Before getting the above errors logs, in the event viewer I have some warnings :

```
EventId: 50

Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
```

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager
EventId: 59

Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
```

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager
EventId: 35

No XML encryptor configured. Key {blablabla} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
```

Not sure about what are these warnings. Maybe they can maybe guide to the right problem.

Also, this is the last log before the error log which shows that the app is successfully started.

```
Application 'X:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\' started successfully.
```

I assumed they were able to share the session between the two applications since they are under the same domain.

Is there something missing ?

Comment: There is no ".net standard framework". If you are using .NET Framework, then say that name.

Comment: @LexLi Noted and rectified. Thanks!

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Indeed there is .NET Standard. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard But just to clarify, in my case, I am talking about .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Comment: can you paste the full stack trace? It appears that your .NET core application failed to connect to AAD server to retrieve endpoint document. Verify if your server can connect to AAD server.

Comment: @ElendilZheng-MSFT I appreciate your help. I've just edited my post with the whole stack trace. I am checking if the server can connect to Azure AD server.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. to share session between application, the key point is to share cookie between cookie, not under the same domain. and the key point to share cookie is the same key to encrypt and decrypt data,just like what you see in the event viewer. The reason is that session will use a aspnet.session cookie to track every connection's session, this cookie is encrypted by asp.net core. To enable to share session between application, your application should be able to share the key to decrypt and encrypt data. these part in asp.net core is called data protection. looks you have not configured the data protection key. 
You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more detail