# ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC lost session of parent website if use iframe to load child website and set session inside of child website

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I have two different website. One is used as a Parent and other is used as a child website of parent website and load it inside an iframe of parent website.

Both sites uses session. I have set the session "UName" in parent site when user logged into the parent site.

Here is my code fragment.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoggedIn(LoginModel login)
{
    if (IsAuthenticated(login.Username, login.Password))
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UName", login.Username);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Configuration");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
}
```

Now I am accessing the one of the parent website page that contains an iframe to load child website and the same way I set the session in child website when the child web page loads.

Now I am trying to access another page of parent website and see that my parent website lost the session "UName" immediately.

If I am accessing both the websites as an individual websites then both sites working fine and no any problem of lost session. If I removed the session set of the child website then it works very fine. But the requirement is that I need session in both the parent site as well as child site.

Both sites are different but why session of parent website lost if I have set the session of child website ?

Comment: Hi @DipakPatel, From your description, it seems that the parent and child website will use the same session key name, if you configure the website share session or authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps, the session value will be replaced if using the same session key name. So, try to use a different session key name, and before get value from session check whether the session is exist or not first. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200092/share-session-between-two-net-core-app-and-net-framework-app-different-applica) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ramil. Actually both website needs to be working as separately also so i don't want to share the parent site session to a child site. I have tried to use the different session name in both the parent and child site but still it lost the session of parent site. The solution is that you will need to set the different cookie name in both the sites to make it working. See my answer.

Comment: Glad to hear you have resolved the problem. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I tried that but it is not possible to vote on my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by setting the different cookie name for each parent and child site in startup.cs file.

Here is my code fragment of parent site:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".Parent.Session";
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        });
```

Here is my code fragment of child site:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".Child.Session";
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        });
```